# Change colour of webpage elements dynamically

Tags: html, dynamic, colors

I am working on a quick website idea and i want to have dynamic color, i know that i can do this with the css code:

```
.col-rotation {
  -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(20deg);
}
```

i have a slider as follows

```
<input type="slider" id="slider" min="0" max="360" value="0">
```

and i am using jquery in an attempt to change the colour with it

```
$("#slider").change(function() {
            val = $("#slider").val();
            $(".col-rot").css("-webkit-filter":"hue-rotate("+val+"deg);");
        });
```

no matter what i try to change here i can't seem to change the colours on the page.. any tips?

Comment: Can you post your code on JSFiddle.net please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a a few errors in your code.
the set up of the slider is not correct.
there are other syntax issues as well.

see working example below

HTML:

```
<div id="slider" min="0" max="360" value="0"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-rot {
width:100px;
height:400px;
border:1px solid black;
background:red;
-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
```

}

JS:

```
$('#slider').slider({
slide: function (even, ui) {
    debugger;
    $(".col-rot").css("-webkit-filter", "hue-rotate(" + ui.value + "deg)");
}

});
```

fidde: http://jsfiddle.net/dDSAL/